# My element is moving strangely after scaling it

Tags: javascript, html

I got an element(canvas) on mouse wheel click you can move it around and on ctrl+scroll u zoom it,to make the movement of the element smoother I calculate the distance of the mouse relative to the element,so the mouse doesnt just go the the top left corner of the element,this distance is being calculated wrong after scaling, I tried different methods multiplying or dividing by scale the distance but still nothing that quite works.Here is the code:

```
 var scale = 1;
 window.addEventListener("wheel", function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
      event.preventDefault(); 
        if(event.deltaY<0){
            if(scale<5)
                scale+=0.2;
                
          }else{
            if(scale>=0.8)
                scale-=0.2;
          }
          canvas.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
      }

    }, { passive: false });
var canvasX,canvasY,movingCanvas = false;
document.addEventListener('mousedown',function(event){
    if(event.button === 1)
    {
        //here somewting needs to be changed according to the scale
        canvasX = (event.clientX- canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left);
        canvasY = (event.clientY- canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top);
        movingCanvas = true;
    }

});
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
document.onmousemove = function(event){
    if(movingCanvas){
        canvas.style.top = (event.clientY-canvasY) +'px';
        canvas.style.left=(event.clientX-canvasX) + 'px';
    }
};
document.addEventListener('mouseup',function(e){
    if(movingCanvas)
        movingCanvas = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright found the problem, the code is alright,it doesnt need changes,the problem was: after scaling, top and left remained in the same place from the unscaled element to fix it I added the property:
`transform-origin: top left;` in css